# Finding and proving a closed form formula for a recursive formula with floor and ceiling functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, induction, recurrence-relations, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I have $T:$ $\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$

Such that $T(1)=1$, 
$T(n)=T(\lfloor n/2 \rfloor) + T(\lceil n/2 \rceil)$ for all $n\ge2$.

My work:

If $n$ is even then $\lceil n/2 \rceil = \lfloor n/2 \rfloor=n/2$.

If $n$ is odd, then we have $\lceil n/2 \rceil -1 = \lfloor n/2 \rfloor=(n-1)/2$.

Using the above results, we have 
\begin{eqnarray*}
T(n)&=&2T(n/2)&\quad\text{ if n is even, }\\
T(n)&=& T((n-1)/2)+ T((n+1)/2)&\quad\text{ if n is odd.}
\end{eqnarray*}
I conjecture that $T(n)=n$ for all n.

I proved the base case for $n=2$ and then assumed that the formula is true for $n=k$. Now I will try to prove that it is also true for $n=k+1$.

I know that $k+1$ can either be odd or even, so I have to consider both possibilities, but i'm not sure how to proceed here. I appreciate any help

Comment: Your definition of $T(n)$ seems to be missing some parentheses, and maybe a $T$? I have attempted to fix it, let me know if I understood correctly.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck The math was syntactically incorrect, and the rest of the question strongly suggested this was the intended meaning. And your edit wasn't a rollback, so don't call it that.

Comment: @Servaes Your edit is correct. Thanks!

Comment: @TheGreatDuck No, it was an edit; versions 1 and 3 are clearly distinct.  Also, the OP has clearly indicated that my edit is correct, making your rollback incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By induction $T(N)=N$; the base case $N=1$ holds by definition.

Suppose $T(n)=n$ for all $n<N$. Then if $N$ is even
$$T(N)=T(\lfloor\tfrac{N}{2}\rfloor)+T(\lceil\tfrac{N}{2}\rceil)=T(\tfrac{N}{2})+T(\tfrac{N}{2})=\tfrac{N}{2}+\tfrac{N}{2}=N,$$
and similarly, if $N$ is odd,
$$T(N)=T(\lfloor\tfrac{N}{2}\rfloor)+T(\lceil\tfrac{N}{2}\rceil)=T(\tfrac{N-1}{2})+T(\tfrac{N+1}{2})=\tfrac{N-1}{2}+\tfrac{N+1}{2}=N.$$
By induction $T(N)=N$ for all $N\in\Bbb{N}$.

Comment: Beware, we need to have $\dfrac{N+1}2<N\iff N>1\iff N\ge 2$ for the induction to be not self-referencing. So $T(2)$ should also be verified as initial step.

Comment: @zwim You are right that this proof of the induction step is only valid for $N\geq2$. But $T(2)$ need not be verified because the base case $N=1$ has already been verified, so the first application of the induction step is with $N=2$.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely $T(n)=n$ is a solution
$$
T\left( n \right) = n = T\left( {\left\lfloor {n/2} \right\rfloor } \right) + \left\lceil {n/2} \right\rceil 
$$
because
$$
n = \left\lfloor {n/2} \right\rfloor  + \left\lceil {n/2} \right\rceil \quad \left| {\;\forall n \in \mathbb Z} \right.
$$
and
$$
T\left( 1 \right) = 1
$$